# Antd v5 Tooltip Selects on click Menu Item

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the following Antd v5 components

- Sider
- Menu
- Tooltip

I implemented a simple case where a Menu item's label is wrapped by a Tooltip.

When I hover over the item, the Tooltip appears. If I click on the Tooltup, the item selection changes.

I don't want that the menu item gets selected although I only clicked on its Tooltip and not directly on the item. Unfortunately, I don't see anything in the API to avoid this.

You may find the following demo also in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5rcyg6?file=demo.tsx)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { DesktopOutlined, PieChartOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { MenuProps, Tooltip } from 'antd';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';

const { Sider } = Layout;

type MenuItem = Required<MenuProps>['items'][number];

function getItem(
  label: React.ReactNode,
  key: React.Key,
  icon?: React.ReactNode,
  children?: MenuItem[]
): MenuItem {
  return {
    key,
    icon,
    children,
    label,
  } as MenuItem;
}

const items: MenuItem[] = [
  getItem('Option 1', '1', <PieChartOutlined />),
  getItem(
    <Tooltip title="Test" placement="right">
      'Option 2'
    </Tooltip>,
    '2',
    <DesktopOutlined />
  ),
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <Sider
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        onCollapse={(value) => setCollapsed(value)}
      >
        <div className="demo-logo-vertical" />
        <Menu
          theme="dark"
          defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
          mode="inline"
          items={items}
        />
      </Sider>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean `I don't want that and I don't see anything in the API to avoid this.`